# Mootools: TypeError: window.addEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla, mootools

Ajax script doesn't work on one site. I used this script on many sites and on most of them is working well.

After debugging with firebug i see this js error:
TypeError: window.addEvent is not a function

What I know about this error? This error can be present if:

- mootools is not loaded on the page
- site calling window.AddEvent() before the mootools library is loaded.

But mootools is loaded on page and script calling window.addEvent is after mootools.

Url where problem is present: www.terapiamusicale.eu/seminario - stars on page must be working, is ajax voting script.

Script is here: http://www.terapiamusicale.eu/plugins/system/microformatsvotes/assets/js/plugin.js

Code:

```
    var plgmfv_box = [];
var plgmfv_timer = null;
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $$('div.plgmfv-inline-rating').each(function(el) {
        var pars = el.id.split('-');
        el.getElements('a.plgmfv-toggler').each(function(tog) {
            tog.addEvent('click', function() {
                if (plgmfv_timer)
                    clearTimeout(plgmfv_timer);
                if ("undefined" == typeof(plgmfv_box[el.id]))
                    plgmfv_box[el.id] = new Fx.Morph(el.getElement('div.plgmfv-box'), {duration:1000, wait:false});
                el.getElement('div.plgmfv-box').set("html", '<img src="'+SITE_ROOT+'plugins/system/microformatsvotes/assets/images/loading.gif" class="loading" />');
                new Request({
                    url: SITE_ROOT+"plugins/system/microformatsvotes/ajax.php",
                    data: {"cid": pars[1], "context": pars[0], "rating": tog.get('text')},
                    timeout: 10000,
                    noCache: true,
                    onComplete: function(response){
                        var json = (JSON.decode) ? JSON.decode(response, false) : JSON.parse(response);;
                        if (!json) return;
                        el.getElement('li#mfv-current-rating').setStyle('width', 20*json.average+'%');
                        plgmfv_box[el.id].start({'opacity': 0}).chain(function() {
                            el.getElement('div.plgmfv-box').set('html', json.message);
                            plgmfv_box[el.id].start({'opacity': 1});
                            plgmfv_timer = function() {
                                plgmfv_box[el.id].start({'opacity': 0}).chain(function() {
                                    el.getElement('div.plgmfv-box').set('html', json.description);
                                    plgmfv_box[el.id].start({'opacity': 1});
                                });
                                plgmfv_timer = null;
                            }.delay(2000);
                        });
                    }
                }).send();
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any help with this mootools error?

Comment: Are you using some script loader like AMD? can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sergio, no, I don't use AMD and I can't reproduce the problem for now - owner of site switch off plugin :( This problem happened only on some ajax powered templates. In this case is template for Joomla with name "Hotel" (gavick.com/joomla-templates/hotel) powered by Gavick.

Comment: if `window.addEvent` is a type error as it can't resolve `addEvent`, means MooTools has not even loaded and the `Element.prototype` has not been extended.

Comment: Dimitar Christoff, mootools is loaded on page and is loaded before this script.

Comment: @EduardDimitrov you should try to provide the minimal case.  All the extra JS after the `window.addEvent(..` is noise (distracting).

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem as I'm getting a 404 on mootools.js.  Open up your developer window (F12 on Windows for all (?) browsers), under the menu top-right for Mac  / Linux) and look at the Network tab.